# Rewrite rule shows 404 page

Tags: url-rewriting, templates

I am new to Wordpress so I don't really know how the rewrite rules should look like. My problem is that I have a custom template in my theme called portfolio-inner.php

My rule looks something like that `['portfolio/php/wordpress'] => 'portfolio-inner/?galid=3'`.

The problem is that all the examples show an `index.php` URL as the destination, but I don't know how to build the `index.php` URL for my template URL.

As a result, that rule shows the 404 page.

As a workaround, I edited the `.htaccess` and added this:

```
Redirect /portfolio/php/wordpress  http://example.com/portfolio-inner/?galid=3
```

and I see the right gallery page, but that's not OK, because the browser's address bar changes and it should remain `/portfolio/php/wordpress`

Comment: You can't rewrite requests directly to template files, that's not how WordPress works. Rewrite rules typically point to a WordPress object of some sort - a page, an archive, a post, etc., via query arguments appended to the main index.php file, which then loads a template file based on the type of request, following [the template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

The `index.php` you see is not the template file. It is pointed to `index.php` file you see in the root of your WordPress installation.

**How does the pretty URL translate into a template file**

1. When a person goes to a URL on your site, the `.htaccess` redirects all requests, that don't match an actual file, to `index.php` to kick off the whole WordPress process.
2. WordPress finds a match for the URL path to the **rewrite rules** using regular expressions.
3. When a match is found, WordPress converts the regular expression for the rule into a query string. If you disable pretty URLs, WordPress will use the same query strings in the URLs.
4. The query string is then parsed into the **query vars** which are defined variables. It will also fill in any implied vars.
5. Then the default `WP_Query` object that is used in the main loop is created based upon the query vars.
6. Then WordPress determines which template to load from the theme base upon the query vars or an override using the `template_redirect` hook.

**How do you override this**

Without fully knowing what you are trying to do, I'm going to answer your question as is. There are probably optimizations for what you are doing.

We will add the custom rewrite rule. You will need to update your permalinks to apply the changes.

```
function my_custom_rewrite_rules( $rewrite ) {
    $rewrite->rules['portfolio/php/wordpress'] = 'index.php?my_portfolio=1&galid=3';
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules' );
```

Because we are using a custom **query var** `my_portfolio`, we need to register it with WordPress.

```
function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
$vars[] = 'my_portfolio';
return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars' );
```

Now we can tell WordPress to use our custom template when our query var `my_portfolio` is true. To use our template, we use `locate_template` to see if the template exists and then call it. If the template exists, it returns `true` to tell it was found.

```
function my_custom_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->get( 'my_portfolio' ) && locate_template( 'portfolio-inner.php', true ) ) {
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_custom_template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a rewrite rule to a page the uses my template.
Also, I had to add galid as a rewrite endpoint for EP_PAGES.
This tutorial helped a lot: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/